# Apache, Django. Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I create a django project under /home/server/

here is what I add to my httpd.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/server/my_server/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/server/
<Directory /home/server/>
   <Files wsgi.py>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
   </Files>
</Directory>
```

The problem is, when I visit localhost, it says

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Shouldn't it be <Files /my_server/wsgi.py> instead of <Files wsgi.py> ?

Comment: Ty aurel.g but it doesn't work

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807176/apache-mod-wsgi-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-s