# Installing Trac on Ubuntu14.04/Apache2/mod_wsgi

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi, trac

I'm trying to install Edgewall's Trac ticket system on an Ubuntu 14.04 Server, with Apache2 and mod_wsgi.
I have followed the instructions given here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TracApacheModWsgi
But after point 9, when i try to view the page, it says:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /trac on this server.

What could be the cause?

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807176/apache-mod-wsgi-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step 6 of the referenced instruction, place line `Require all granted` before the closing tag `</Directory>`. This is required in order to access directories outside of the default document root.

Please note that under Ubuntu 14.04 you might get a python babel package error that is related to missing "en_US" locale. It can be easily fixed:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-babel-localedata
```

Comment: Meanwhile, i fixed the issue. The "Require all granted" was indeed one important change i had to make. I am not 100% if i did other things as well. I didn't run into the locale problem though.