# Apache and Django Error forbidden and access to server

Tags: python, django, apache

I want to deploy my Django project on my apache server but even if I follow django's example in deploying with apache I get a 403 Error. I am using:

1. django 1.6
2. apache 2.4.7
3. python 2.6.x

My wsgi.py is the one created by django-admin startproject

```
import os, sys

#root = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..')
# sys.path.insert(0, root)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "rhombus.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My VirutalServer conf file is the following

rhombus.conf

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/rhombus2

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmast@rhombus.com
    ServerName myrhombus.com
    ServerAlias www.myrhombus.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/rhombus2
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/rhombus2/rhombus/wsgi.py
    <Directory /var/www/rhombus2/rhombus>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and I have placed rhombus2 inside /var/www. All foldters and files are at 755 with `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/rhombus2`. But even with that I get a Forbidden Error.

Among other things, when I remove the WSGIPythonPath, I don't get Import Error, which I probably should. I know it is not the secure way to have everything (code too) under document root. But I really need to have it working first, and then make it secure. Is there something wrong with my code?

EDIT: error.log

```
(13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:46669] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/avlahop/development/django') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

Not sure why it's showing me this path, cause there isn't it anywhere in my rhombus.conf.

EDIT2: I also don't have any other site enabled. My  hosts file has the following line

```
127.0.0.1    www.myrhombus.com
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my working virtualhost

```
Listen 9090
<VirtualHost *:9090>
    ServerName www.test.com
    WSGIDaemonProcess   project processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup project
    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/project/project/wsgi.py
    Alias /static /srv/www/project/static/
    Alias /favicon.ico /srv/www/project/static/favicon.ico

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    LogLevel Info
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and wsgi.py

```
import os, sys, site

from os.path import dirname, abspath, join
site.addsitedir('/home/user/virtualenvy/some_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "some_project.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I hope it helps You :)

Comment: thx @qwetty. Though i  am not under virtualenv...Where does apache 2 gets the problematic path? Which is 755 in permissions too

Comment: Do You try to add `Alias /favicon.ico` in virtualhost configuration? Almost any browser automatically requests for this file.

Comment: No, I didn't but why is it seeking for it in wrong path. Different from my VirtualHost conf Added 
    Alias /media/ /var/www/rhombus2/media/
    Alias /static/ /var/www/rhombus2/static/
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/rhombus2/static/favicon.ico

Not working

Comment: From other side. Where apache should take information about path, while You didn't specify ... ?

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to tell me. Where apache should do what?

Comment: I didn't see your previous comment. If You add Alias for favicon and it steel doesn't work, unfortunately I can't help You :(

Answer (score 0):

Assume that Appache's username is `www-data`, run this command to check `www-data`'s permission on your application folder: `sudo su - www-data -s /bin/bash -c 'ls /var/www/rhombus2/rhombus/'`

Since you did chmod 755 the folder, so I think it'll work, if not, check permisson of `/var` and `/var/www`

Also, paste content of `wsgi.py` might be helpful for solving problem.

Comment: wsgi.py code is at my initial post You can check it out. Thanks for answering

Comment: But where's the rest of that wsgi file? That's not the whole code that's created by Django. You need the bit that actually creates the WSGI application object.

Comment: You are right...added it too Also your command listed the files inside /var/www/rhombus2/rhombus, so it probably works

Comment: @Apostolos: did you solve your problem? I think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807176/apache-mod-wsgi-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-s?rq=1) might be useful

Comment: I did it back from the beginning and put everything inside /srv/www/{mysitename}} and worked :)